# Using Flash IDE to link nodes for Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: flash, path-finding, ide

I'm trying to use plash to set up the node connections, but having a really hard time to use the IDE as a tool to do so. Before giving up completely, and getting into creating a tool that would take assets and encode the information (by placing nodes and allowing one to drag links from one to another), I wanted to put this question out there and see if anyone has any idea how I can show a connection between these nodes as a line.

Drawing actual lines is not working well, because lines have to be moved as objects are updated, they are imprecise, and cannot carry weight information.

I'm experimenting with components and live views, which allows placement of nodes, but I can't get it to draw the lines.

I don't want to forgo using the connections completely, because it could make paths that go through objects unless I set up low proximity settings, which would require way too many objects.

Comment: It's kinda hard to tell what the problem is from this question alone, with no code to read and only a vague description of the problem.
As far is i can imagine the lines would be a terrible place to show weight info, you could draw the nodes themselves (as circles maybe?) for that.
You can also just draw the lines from code, which would make them as precise as they would need to be.

Comment: The problem I'm having is "hacking" the ide to show lines between objects while in editing mode (not compiled), I can use live preview of components to draw a line in real time while editing, but I'm having a hard time getting the coordinates of other live view instances